# Converting numeric to two decimal(10,2)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried too many way but could get exact right answer.

```
SELECT 
        CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC('9900') != 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE  CAST('9900' AS decimal(10,2))/100 
        END
       AS BVN
```

In this case output is 99.000000, However I want output 99.00, so I tried this:

```
SELECT 
        CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC('9900') != 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE  REPLACE(CAST(CAST('9900' AS decimal(10,2))/100 AS VARCHAR(20)),'0000','')
        END
       AS BVN
```

Now I got error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '99.00' to data type int.
```

I am confused Why I am getting error as I have already casted result to varchar and then using REPLACE function.
And how can I get my desired output.

Comment: `numeric` is a synonym for `decimal`. What you have is a string, not a number

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a *terrible* function, don't use it. Despite it's name, it does **not** tell you if the value will convert to a `numeric`/`decimal`, it tells you if it *might* convert to *any* of the numerical data types (and even then it can be wrong). Use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: `CAST` and `CONVERT` are used for parsing, not arithmetic operations like division. Parse `'9900'` first and *then* divide it to convert it to `99.00`, eg `cast('9900' as int)/100.00`

Comment: @Larnu: do you happen to have an example of where `ISNUMERIC` is flat-out wrong (as in, it gives 1 when there is no type that will accept a conversion, or 0 when there is)? I'm aware of many peculiarities, but not cases where it is incorrect even by T-SQL's own, bizarre, standards.

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC(''), CONVERT(int,'')` , @JeroenMostert .

Comment: @Larnu: I never thought I'd say this, but... treating the empty string as a special case is probably a good call from `ISNUMERIC`, even though it's an inconsistency. Not that it makes it any more useful.

Comment: I don't strictly disagree, but the thing is, even SQL Server isn't consistent with an empty string, @JeroenMostert . `CONVERT(decimal,'')` errors, but then `float`, `money`, `bit` all return `0`. So the *only* data type that doesn't convert `''` to `0` is `numeric`/`decimal` yet `ISNUMERIC` says `0` (which implies it won't convert to *any* of them). It's just a *bad* function.

Comment: @Larnu: oh yes, no argument there. On the positive side, it correctly signals that you can use D&D rolls in T-SQL: `ISNUMERIC('2d10')`. (Disclaimer: do not actually use for tabletop purposes, the value might not be what you expect.)

Comment: I'd be very happy if when rolling `'2d6'` I got a number that high in table top games I play, @JeroenMostert; I'm normally happy with 8+.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the result to 2 decimal places after the division. Please find the below solution.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('9900' AS decimal(10,2))/100 AS decimal(10,2)) AS BVN
```